# Is there a word or phrase for "taking the long way around a square"?

Tags: phrase-requests

A new apartment building is going up on our block, and the sidewalks are closed on that side of the block.  "Oh well," I told my wife, "we'll just have to...wait, I swear there's a phrase for traversing the other three sides of the square instead of just taking the straight-line route, but I'm not coming up with it..."

Am I crazy, or is there a phrase for taking a route like this around a square?

```
A  ->
+------+
|      | |
|      | v
+------+
B  <-
```

Comment: "Walk the perimeter"? Use the "manhattan distance" or "taxicab route" (where diagonals are prohibited)? The [*rectilinear* distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)? The opposite, of course, is "as the crow flies", the existence of which idiom suggests this (Manhattan distance) is the nominal or normal case, and may not have been given a specific name.

Comment: You looking for *circuitous* or a synonym?

Comment: "To go the long way around" (AmE) or "To go the long way round" (BrE).

Comment: I swear there was an actual phrase for this, from geometry or sewing or something, not just a generic word for going the long way.  "Sewing a pillowcase"? :)

Comment: Maybe "circumnavigate"? The definition isn't quite as strict as the one you gave, but it seems related.

Comment: @DanBron This isn't Manhattan distance -  that would be relevant if he were trying to get to the point diagonal from him, but he's not. Take another look at the diagram.

Comment: @Amadeus9 Fair enough, you are correct, I didn't read the question carefully enough. Thanks.

Comment: I've heard "going 'round Robin Hood's barn".

Comment: "Go around the block" is how I would say it for the specific case of a street grid.

Answer (score 15):

<sub>*This may not be a direct answer to the question, but it will get there, eventually*</sub>

**Scenic route** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scenic-route)

> *noun, informal* the long route or way to a destination; a road or path designed to take one past a pleasant view or nice scenery and usually less direct
>   *"We **took the scenic route** home after having trouble reading the map."*

> The long route or way, often due to one's losing one's way
>   *"missed the Garden State Parkway and ended up taking the scenic route."*

Answer (score 14):

"Go the long way around" (AmE) or "Go the long way round" (BrE).

Comment: "The long way round" is perfectly fine in AmE as well, at least in my dialect.

Comment: In my dialect, it is *take* the long way (the *(a)round* is optional), but *go* is perfectly understandable.

Comment: @PeterShor The "square candies that look round" joke in *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory* made no sense to me until I was comfortably in adulthood, so I would guess it varies. I think one funny thing going on in "American English" is that we are now watching many more shows filmed in "British English" and, at least in my area, I hear a lot more British-isms than ever before, so the lines are blurring. I definitely use plural pronouns to refer to my favorite football.. errr, I mean soccer(?) team - probably from watching so much BrEng commentary.

Answer (score 2):

**Detour** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/detour)

> *noun* 1.1. An alternative route for use by traffic when the usual road is temporarily closed.
> *"A closed road and a detour on the way, but I manage to find my way around that."*
>
> *verb* 1. Take a long or roundabout route
> *"he detoured around the walls."*

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's just "***go around***" or "***go round***":

> **[go around or go round](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+around)**:
>
> v.
>
> 1. To form or follow an indirect path that avoids something: Go around the fence if the gate is locked.
>    Don't try to cross the marsh—go around.