# succinct description for circuitous and unnecessary, wasteful, or odd

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or idiom for coming to a solution through unnecessarily convoluted means?

I think similar to the question [Is there a word or phrase for "taking the long way around a square"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339209/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-taking-the-long-way-around-a-square/339210#339210) but where the circuitous route isn't forced but a result of error or ignorance.

I have a particular illustration that frequently comes to mind when describing unnecessary transformations (`y = x - 2; y += 2`).

While reviewing counterproductive strategies that all arrived at the correct answer, a lecturer said "you can solve the problem like this, just like you can eat like this". He put his arm over his head and bent it around to the other side of his face and touched his upside down hand to his mouth.

"Eating with an upside down hand" isn't yet ubiquitous enough for anyone to know what I'm talking about

Edit: Oops! I think this is a duplicate

[What's an idiom for doing something in an unnecessarily complicated way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43372/whats-an-idiom-for-doing-something-in-an-unnecessarily-complicated-way)

Comment: elegant versus messy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> crossing a river to get water

from
[@miros](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160069/miros)
in the comments of [What's an idiom for doing something in an unnecessarily complicated way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43372/whats-an-idiom-for-doing-something-in-an-unnecessarily-complicated-way)